# How can I replicate something similar to querySelector in browsers like IE 7 and 6?

Tags: javascript, optimization, css-selectors

I've messed around with trying to detect how complex the query is (like if it's just an ID selector, it goes through getElementById instead and such) but this is clearly no way to do complex CSS queries and will probably fail on a certain few selectors.

So my question is to anyone who's done something similar, how did you end up replicating it for older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com)? Or at least a selector library like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/). No point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I'm making this for a personal project of mine that I'm trying to keep it as lightweight as possible. I might have to take a look through Sizzles source code though, I completely forgot it existed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For predictable support for wide range of selectors go with Sizzle (or jQuery which uses Sizzle)

Otherwise you could use the snippet from: 
[Creating a querySelector for IE that runs at “native speed” - Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/creating-a-queryselector-for-ie-that-runs-at-native-speed)

```
if (!document.querySelector)
    document.querySelector = function(selector) {
        var head = document.documentElement.firstChild;
        var styleTag = document.createElement("STYLE");
        head.appendChild(styleTag);
        document.__qsResult = [];

        styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsResult.push(this))}";
        window.scrollBy(0, 0);
        head.removeChild(styleTag);

        var result = [];
        for (var i in document.__qsResult) {
            result.push(document.__qsResult[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This code isn't going to work Bob, I have tested it on IE7, IE7 IEtester, and in modern browsers when `document.querySelector = function...` renamed to `document.customQuerySelector = function...`. To be specific: `styleTag.styleSheet` turns to be undefined.